# Rapidclipse X 10.4 Error 404 within demo project

Tags: java, http-status-code-404, rapidclipse

I installed RapidClipse X 10.4 and created the "Demo1" project.

[Demo 1 Project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7K4ov.png)

When I start it under "Tomcat 10", the page is not found and the message "HTTP Status 404" appears.

[Start "Demo1 with Tomcat 10.0](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uzPZj.png)

[Http 404](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xvm5X.png)

Any ideas? I would be happy if I got an answer.

Greetings
Hannes

Comment: Try with Tomcat 9

Answer (score 0):

This should definitely work, same thing happens when I try with Tomcat 10. I opened an issue for this. https://xdevsoftware.atlassian.net/browse/XWS-2002

Comment: Thx. We will see what happen. At the moment there is no answer there.